# Express not able to route HTML properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a website with Express. My main problem is that I couldn't find a way to link the navigation bar tabs together.

**index.html**

```
<!--HEADER-->

<div class="header">
    <!--logo-->
  <div class="logo_container">
      <img src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
    <!--profile icon-->
  <div class="ID_container">
    <a href="login.html"><img src="images\ID.png" alt="ID"><a>
  </div>
    <!--navigation tabs-->
 <div class="inner_header">
   <ul class="navigation">
     <a href="OurPool.html" target="_blank"><li>Our Pool</li> </a>
     <a href="index.html" target="_blank"><li>Network</li> </a>
     <a href="error.html" target="_blank"><li>Explorer</li> </a>

   </div>
 </div>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var path = require('path')


app.use(express.static('website/public'))



const port = 5555

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

        
        res.sendFile('index.html', {root:path.join(__dirname,'public')});



})




app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

The problem is when the user lands on `index.html` and wants to access to `OurPool.html`, for example. This gets the following error message:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an appropriate route for this endpoint as you did for `index.html`:

```
app.get('/OurPool.html', function(req, res) {     
  res.sendFile('OurPool.html', {root:path.join(__dirname,'public')});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not handling a request route for `/ourpool` in the `app.get` method. You are sending only the `index.html` file when user lands on your site. In this case default route is `/`.

Try adding this to your code:

```
app.get('/ourpool', function(req, res) {

res.sendFile('OurPool.html', {root:path.join(__dirname,'public')});

})
```